# Como mudar da segunda para a terceira tela?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Há pouco tempo comecei a desenvolver um pequeno aplicativo que se baseia totalmente na mudança de telas a partir de botões. Ainda há muitos detalhes para serem resolvidos, mas o que me preocupa agora é como fazer o comando para mudar de tela. Já consegui fazer a mudança da 1° tela para a 2°, mas estando nessa segunda tela, não sei como ir para uma terceira.

Esse é o código que estou utilizando para ir da tela inicial para a seguinte.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Entrar extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entrar);


    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        }

    });

}}
```

Agora, gostaria que clicando em um botão (chamado "buttonEntrar") presente na tela que é chamada por esse comando, fosse direcionada a um terceiro layout (chamado "cnaps.xml"), já tentei fazer de maneira semelhante a que havia feito, mas não deu certo, como proceder?

Código da segunda tela:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:fontFamily="@font/tw_cen"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    android:text="VOLTAR"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:onClick="GotoMain"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonEntrar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/tw_cen"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="ENTRAR"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
    android:fontFamily="@font/tw_cen"
    android:text="Insira E-mail:"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
    android:fontFamily="@font/tw_cen"
    android:text="Insira Senha:"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="226dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="205dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="143dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/tw_cen"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Esqueci minha senha!" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="81dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/campus_relief"
    android:text="CNAPS"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Comment: Adiciona o código da segunda tela, na qual quer chamar a terceira tela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você deseja é isto aqui, dentro do método `onClick()` do botão que você for criar:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOndeVoceEsta.this, ActivityParaOndeVoceQuerIr.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Faça isso, inclusive, para essa *activity* de login que você já implementou.

Não se esqueça de adicionar as novas *activities* no `manifest.xml`

Aprenda mais sobre iniciar uma nova *activity* [aqui](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity).